# Python if statement without indent

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working with an inherited Python program, which runs OK, but does not have correct Python indenting.

```
if not arg_o:
print >> sys.stderr, 'Output file needed.'
print >> sys.stderr, usage
exit()
```

What is going on here? Shouldn't the code below the **if** be indented?

**SOLVED**

See the accepted answer. It turns out that TextMate was not properly displaying the tabs, which is a worry. When opened in Vim it was indented properly.

Comment: Do you not get an error when you try to run it?

Comment: Are you sure thats python code? what is `>>` ?

Comment: The program runs and produces output. I don't know if it comes to this branch. Before I try and refactor it I want to understand how it could be working.

Comment: Could this be some obscure whitespace which your editor renders inappropriately?

Comment: Whats the complete code?

Comment: The complete code is here https://code.google.com/p/mpprimer/downloads/list

Comment: There are other examples of non-indented code in this program (MPprimer-1.4-64.7z)

Comment: Which line? which file?

Comment: Line 170 in MPprimer.py

Comment: @AnandSKumar: `print >>` is valid Python, see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement.

Comment: @ardochhigh I did not do it but you might wish to add some details of the discussion to the question. It was quite relevant to finding an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After checking the file - `MPprimer.py` - from the code found [here](https://code.google.com/p/mpprimer/downloads/list) .

I can see the following lines in it -

```
if not arg_o:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Output file needed.'
    print >> sys.stderr, usage
    exit()
```

Starting at line 175 . The issue is that this script mixes tabs and spaces.

The line 175 - `if not arg_o:` -  uses 4 spaces as indentation.

whereas , the next line, line 176 - `print >> sys.stderr, 'Output file needed.'` - uses a tab as indentation.

In Python 2.x , tabs and spaces can be mixed, but a tab is internally represented by 8 spaces.

But in some editors (like Notepad ++ , in my System) , tab is only interpreted as 4 spaces. So even though in those editors they look like they are not correctly indented, they are actually correctly indented , according to python.

Please note, it is not a good practice to mix tabs and spaces, Python 3.x , would error out if you mix them in the same script.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check. I see only tabs for each of those lines. I am using TextMate.

Comment: Wow you are right! It looks fine when I open it on Vim on Linux. Thank you so much for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the whitespace before `if` is 4 spaces, before `print` it is a tab. Your editor might show the tab as something else than Python interprets it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) says that it's incorrect. It should be like this:

```
if not arg_o:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Output file needed.'
    print >> sys.stderr, usage
exit()
```

Maybe your output comes from another part of the code.

Comment: Thats not the question.

Comment: OP is asking how the code *works*. Not how to fix it - it's already fixed!... apparently.

Answer (score 0):

yes the short answer to your question is the code after the If statement should be indented to fallow proper python indentations.

Answer (score -1):

Python indentation need 4 whitespaces so after if the entire block of if should have 4 white spaces

Also print >> does not seem to be python code so refer to https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: It doesn't need _four_, it just needs _some_. Four is the convention, but that amount isn't a requirement.

Comment: [`print >>` is valid Python 2 code.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)  It's used to specify a filehandle to print to.